# How to set the colorbar size and label in a subplot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar

I have the following subplot, and to print the images I'm using the `imagesc`  command. How can I make the size of the color bar matching the two plots and a label stating "[m]" or "[deg]" just right next to the color bar (written with horizontal alignment)?

```
f_prova3 = figure();
s1 = subplot(1,2,1); imagesc(DEM); axis equal; axis off;
hb1 = colorbar('location','eastoutside');
s2 = subplot(1,2,2); imagesc(slopeMap_int); colormap jet, axis equal;axis off;
hb2 = colorbar('location','eastoutside');
```

Sorry, it seems I can not add the image directly. Thanks for Your help

Comment: Please include a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @LuisMendo I'd like to add more but I can't. DEM and slopeMap_int are square matrices of size 512x512 and 508x508 pixels respectively. They portrays a picture of the terrain depths and of the computed slopes. I can't include those. As minimum working example I have included that code. What can I add in order to achieve what I would like?

Comment: It probably suffices if you define a toy example for `DEM` and `slopeMap_int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `axis tight` to adjust the height and use label properties to adjust the labels:

```
DEM = magic(5);
slopeMap_int = magic(5);

f_prova3 = figure();
s1 = subplot(1,2,1); imagesc(DEM); axis equal; axis tight; axis off;
hb1 = colorbar('location','eastoutside');
s2 = subplot(1,2,2); imagesc(slopeMap_int); colormap jet; axis equal; axis tight; axis off;
hb2 = colorbar('location','eastoutside');

hb1.Label.String = '[m]';
hb1.Label.Rotation = 0;
hb1.Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'Left';

hb2.Label.String = '[deg]';
hb2.Label.Rotation = 0;
hb2.Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'Left';
```

I tested in Matlab R2016a.

Comment: Nice! You don't have to replace it, just add the `axes tight`. Otherwise, you will still see the axis labels.

Comment: @EBH, thanks, you are right, I corrected my answer accordingly

Comment: @David if I'd like to place the label string exactly on top of colorbar how can I do it?

        hb1.Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'Center';
        hb1.Label.VerticalAlignment = 'Top';

do not produce the desired output

Comment: Try to set it manually: `hb1.Label.Position = [0 30];` see also https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html